# Name columns within aggregate in R

Tags: r, rename, aggregate

I know I can *re*name columns after I aggregate the data:

```
blubb <- aggregate(dat$two ~ dat$one, ...)
colnames(blubb) <- c("One", "Two")
```

Nothing wrong with that. But is there a way to aggregate and name the columns in one go? Sort of like:

```
blubb <- aggregate( ... , cols = c("One", "Two"))
```

It would be escpecially nice (and typo-proof) to somehow catch the original column names and do like:

```
blubb <- aggregate( ... , cols = c(name_of_dat$one, name_of_dat$two."_Mean"))
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use `setNames` as in:

```
blubb <- setNames(aggregate(dat$two ~ dat$one, ...), c("One", "Two"))
```

Alternatively, you can bypass the slick formula method, and use syntax like:

```
blubb <- aggregate(list(One = dat$one), list(Two = dat$two), ...)
```

---

#### Update

This update is to just help get you started on deriving a solution on your own.

If you inspect the code for `stats:::aggregate.formula`, you'll see the following lines towards the end:

```
if (is.matrix(mf[[1L]])) {
    lhs <- as.data.frame(mf[[1L]])
    names(lhs) <- as.character(m[[2L]][[2L]])[-1L]
    aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...)
}
else aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...)
```

If all that you want to do is append the function name to the variable that was aggregated, perhaps you can change that to something like:

```
if (is.matrix(mf[[1L]])) {
  lhs <- as.data.frame(mf[[1L]])
  names(lhs) <- as.character(m[[2L]][[2L]])[-1L]
  myOut <- aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...)
  colnames(myOut) <- c(names(mf[-1L]), 
                       paste(names(lhs), deparse(substitute(FUN)), sep = "."))
}
else {
  myOut <- aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...)
  colnames(myOut) <- c(names(mf[-1L]), 
                       paste(strsplit(gsub("cbind\\(|\\)|\\s", "", 
                                           names(mf[1L])), ",")[[1]],
                             deparse(substitute(FUN)), sep = "."))
} 
myOut
```

This basically captures the value entered for `FUN` by using `deparse(substitute(FUN))`, so you can probably modify the function to accept a custom suffix, or perhaps even a vector of suffixes. This can probably be improved a bit with some work, but I'm not going to do it!

Here is [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/5123896) with this concept applied, creating a function named "myAgg".

Here is some sample output *of just the resulting column names*:

```
> names(myAgg(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, mean))
[1] "feed"        "weight.mean"
> names(myAgg(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks, sum))
[1] "wool"       "tension"    "breaks.sum"
> names(myAgg(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, FUN = function(x) mean(x^2)))
[1] "feed"                         "weight.function(x) mean(x^2)"
```

Notice that only the aggregated variable name changes. But notice also that if you use a custom function, you'll end up with a really strange column name!

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that it is definitely impossible to set the column names inside the aggregate() parenthesis? Also, I edited my question, maybe you have further ideas on the second half of my question.

Comment: I like the alternative :-)

Comment: I'll look into your problem in a little while. In the meantime, take a look at [this wrapper](https://github.com/mrdwab/AMsnippets/blob/master/R/aggregate2.R) around `aggregate`, which appends the function applied to the aggregated column name. I'm not posting it within my answer because it does limit the functionality of `aggregate` somewhat, and was just written for a project I was working on.

Comment: It's also possible to use the names without list(). `blubb <- aggregate(One = dat$one, Two = dat$two, data=dat...)`

Comment: @Matt, (1) that doesn't seem to work for me, (2) how would that work for more than one grouping variable, (3) why would you need `dat$` if you specify `data=dat` (which is an argument to the `formula` method for `aggregate`, not the method you're proposing here). If I'm missing something, do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Late comment, but how could I do it if I have e.g. blubb <- aggregate(one ~two, FUN = function(x) c("mean" = mean(x), "median" = median(x))? So multiple output columns

Answer (score 13):

The answer to your first question is yes. You can certainly include the column names in the aggregate function. Using the names from your example above:

`blubb <- aggregate(dat,list(One=dat$One,Two=dat$Two),sum)`

I like the part about possibly pulling in the original column names automatically. If I figure it out I'll post it.

Comment: And how do you change the name of the column that results from the function `sum`?  Right now it's just `x`

Comment: @andrewj I believe you can just stick it in the 'list' portion of the function e.g. ...list(One = dat$One, Two = dat$Two, MyResults = dat$x) ...

Comment: To follow up, I think `x` still remains unnamed.  In `list(One=dat$One,` etc.`)` that will name the grouping variable but not `x`.

Answer (score 11):

In case you prefer writing aggregates as `formula` the documentation shows the usage of `cbind`. And `cbind` allows you to name its arguments, which are used by `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(cbind(SLength = Sepal.Length) ~ cbind(Type = Species),
  data = iris, mean)
#  Type SLength
#1    1   5.006
#2    2   5.936
#3    3   6.588
```

But `cbind` replaces `factors` by their internal codes and when used on the right side of `~` it keeps the `cbind` call in the result. To avoid this the new names can already be given in the input data set using `transform` or `within`

```
aggregate(SLength ~ Type, transform(iris, SLength = Sepal.Length,
   Type = Species), mean)
#        Type SLength
#1     setosa   5.006
#2 versicolor   5.936
#3  virginica   6.588
```

or

```
aggregate(cbind(SLength = Sepal.Length) ~ Type, transform(iris, Type = Species),
  mean)
#        Type SLength
#1     setosa   5.006
#2 versicolor   5.936
#3  virginica   6.588
```

The advantage of using `cbind` or `data.frame` compared to `list` is that not all columns need to be given a (new) name. Aggregation of more than one column by more than one grouping factor could be done like:

```
aggregate(cbind("Miles/gallon" = mpg, Weight = wt, hp) ~ Cylinders + Carburetors
          + gear, transform(mtcars, Cylinders = cyl, Carburetors = carb), mean)
#   Cylinders Carburetors gear Miles/gallon  Weight    hp
#1          4           1    3        21.50 2.46500  97.0
#2          6           1    3        19.75 3.33750 107.5
#...
```

and if you want to use more than one function:

```
aggregate(cbind(cases=ncases, ncontrols) ~ alc + tobgp, transform(esoph,
  alc=alcgp), FUN = function(x) c("mean" = mean(x), "median" = median(x)))
#         alc    tobgp cases.mean cases.median ncontrols.mean ncontrols.median
#1  0-39g/day 0-9g/day  1.5000000    1.0000000      42.000000        44.000000
#2      40-79 0-9g/day  5.6666667    4.0000000      24.166667        29.000000
#...
```

which adds to the colname the used aggregate-function.

Some examples to aggregate `mpg` renamed to `Miles/gallon` and hp by `cyl` renamed to `Cylinders` and `gear` using `mtcars` resulting in:

```
#  Cylinders gear Miles/gallon       hp
#1         4    3       21.500  97.0000
#2         6    3       19.750 107.5000
#3         8    3       15.050 194.1667
#4         4    4       26.925  76.0000
#5         6    4       19.750 116.5000
#6         4    5       28.200 102.0000
#7         6    5       19.700 175.0000
#8         8    5       15.400 299.5000
```

```
aggregate(cbind("Miles/gallon" = mpg, hp) ~ Cylinders + gear,
          transform(mtcars, Cylinders = cyl, Carburetors = carb), mean)

with(mtcars, aggregate(cbind("Miles/gallon" = mpg, hp),
                       data.frame(Cylinders = cyl, gear), mean))

with(mtcars, aggregate(data.frame("Miles/gallon" = mpg, hp),
                       data.frame(Cylinders = cyl, gear), mean))
```

Comment: This looks better than all the other solutions. Naming through `cbind` allows for more complex cases than `list`, and avoids post-hoc operations that rely on knowing the order of the output columns in advance and might become outdated if the formula is modified.

Answer (score -4):

```
w <- data.frame(Funding<-"Fully Insured",Region="North East",claim_count=rnbinom(1000, 300.503572818, mu= 0.5739467))
x <- data.frame(Funding<-"Fully Insured",Region="South East",claim_count=rnbinom(1000, 1000, mu= 0.70000000))
y <- data.frame(Funding<-"Self Insured",Region="North East",claim_count=rnbinom(1000, 400, mu= 0.80000000))
z <- data.frame(Funding<-"Self Insured",Region="South East",claim_count=rnbinom(1000, 700, mu= 1.70000000))
names(w)<-c("Funding","Region","claim_count")
names(x)<-c("Funding","Region","claim_count")
names(y)<-c("Funding","Region","claim_count")
names(z)<-c("Funding","Region","claim_count")
my_df <- rbind(w,x,y,z)
my_df2<-with(my_df, aggregate(x=claim_count, by=list(Funding,Region), FUN=sum))
colnames(my_df2)<-colnames(my_df)
```