# How to filter data based on a column name dynamically in R?

Tags: r

I am performing a routine in R, where I need to sum a variable by group. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group) and used `aggregate`. It works fine when I `hardcode` the column names such as `Category` and `Frequency`.

```
Category     Frequency
First        10
First        15
First        5
Second       2
Third        14
Third        20
Second       3
```

But, my situation is that, these column names must be assigned `dynamically` in run-time. These columns are created during run-time based on some manipulation. So, if I try to access the column name with a variable like this -

`x_axis_column <- input$x_axis`

and try to use the aggregate function, I get an error as shown below -

`Error in FUN: invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

This is the code that I tried -

`counted <- aggregate(item~x_axis_column, data, sum)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Alternatively, `aggregate(formula(paste(item, "~", x_axis_column)), data, sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the column names are stored in a variable, we cannot directly utilise them. One way is to use the variables to subset the dataframe.

```
aggregate(df[item], df[x_axis_column], sum)

#  Category Frequency
#1    First        30
#2   Second         5
#3    Third        34
```

Or another option is with using formula and `get`

```
aggregate(get(item)~get(x_axis_column), df, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I get the column names of the new data-frame as `get(item)` and `get(x_axis_column)`. Why is that so?

Comment: @DLML you can use another option provided, or use `setnames` with `get`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309205/name-columns-within-aggregate-in-r).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
      group_by_(x_axis_column) %>% 
      summarise(Frequency = sum(get(item)))
```